# How to extract first substring from string with multiple hits

Tags: javascript, for-loop, substring

Ok. New to code, and wow, do I like it! But still a newbie, so be patient. I'm working with JS.

So, I'm trying to loop through a string to find vowels. When I find the first vowel in a string I want to store all previous characters in a variable. For example: *spacing* would render *sp*. Problem is that I get multiple hits since the loop continues to the end of the string and finds more vowels along the way, also giving *ng*, in this, case as an outcome.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        if ("a" === text[i] || "e" === text[i] || "i" === text[i] || "o" === text[i] || "u" === text[i] || "y" === text[i]) {
            var textTrimmed = text.substring(0, i);
        }
}
```

So: storing the first hit?
Anyone knows a neat trick I can use, and understand?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a "neat trick," I might suggest using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). The `sliceBeforeFirstVowel` function searches for and returns any consecutive non-vowels at the beginning of a string, case-insensitively. I have included `y` as per your code, but note that it doesn't always serve as a vowel so the function name might be a bit misleading.

```js
function sliceBeforeFirstVowel (text) {
    return /^[^aeiouy]*/i.exec(text)[0]
}

console.log('spacing ->', sliceBeforeFirstVowel('spacing'))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use the `break`, which will take you out of the `for` loop.

Comment: But a break won't do anything in this since it loops all through and then breaks, right? Or could you maybe show me how you're thinking?

Comment: @DjangoJoe Nope, a `break;` always breaks the loop. Just place it right below the `var textTrimmed` line.

Comment: the break will only occur when you enter the if condition so your'e going to take the values you need and  just them break..